# Informix ODBC driver issue :ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: .net-core, odbc, informix

I have a .net core app which connects to Informix database for operation. After deploying the app in server I am getting the error "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".

I have already installed IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER :both 32 bit and 64 bit. And I could see both are available in ODBC drivers.

OS available in server is windows 2016 -64 bit.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using a DSN, double check that the DSN you have created is either user or system. Your .NET app may be running as a different user (eg. local system account) so it may not have access to the same DSN you see when you log as a normal user. If you are not using a DNS and just specify the driver name, host, port, in the connection string directly, make sure the name is right. The name of the driver difers from 32-bit to 64. 64 has an extra "(64-bit)" suffix.

Comment: @jsagrera exactly.. this was the issue...I figured it out and resolved now. Many thanks..

Comment: @jsagrera ODBC drive has an extra suffix "(64-bit)". When I added this suffix in connection string, issue got resolved.

Comment: Good that you got it fixed. One thing I forgot to add in my comment (which you may already know) is that, in CSDK 4.50 (for Linux and Windows), we included a new Informix .NET Core provider so there is no need to use the MS ODBC one.